# My edit suggestion get rejected without reason. Why?

Tags: discussion, editing

Can anyone please tell me the reason to rejected my edit suggestion by Magento Stack Exchange users.

I  just corrected the spellings only for the words

**DESIGN** and **CHANGE**.

You can find that at https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/89261

Comment: question is related to meta site

Comment: this is not place to discuss these kind of matters.

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara it will moved by higher authorities (MOD) not me

Comment: @QaisarSatti sir, it just moved to meta site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why my edit suggestion is rejected?](http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1059/why-my-edit-suggestion-is-rejected)

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/90043 rejected this edit

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala, Hi Brother. Yeah i found. i dont worry becoz i realized with your explanation. that completely based on reviewer opinion. thanks for spending time.

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara Please stop bumping the question which is not REALLY useful for community, in no way this question will give notifications to the members rejected your edit so it is waste of time instead keep moving and help community with answers or USEFUL questions.

Answer (score 7):

> I just corrected the spellings only for the words
>
> DESIGN and CHANGE.

"only", that's the point. There are so many grammatical errors in the post that fixing two small typos is not really an improvement. Personally I would be on the fence about accepting or rejecting this edit.

But keep in mind that your suggestions have to be reviewed by at least three people, so try not to waste their time with edits that don't add value.

Answer (score 4):

This edit **should  be approve**. My Suggestion to **@liyakat and @vaibhav ahalpara**,  should  approve this suggestion.This edit-suggestion have usefully for The community.So, please invest more time for *reviewing edit-suggestion*

Comment: Hi Amit. Thanks for consider.

Comment: agree with you but  It still upto @reviewer  and we must respect the opinion.

Comment: Yes, I do not tell u That not respect to other reviewer but this is a basic things for reviewer. For a reviewer, we should follow this.

Comment: If  we reject thia edit  then  editor will lose interested on edition

Comment: The same goes for edit suggestions: please invest more time to actually make them useful.

Comment: I am agree with you

Answer (score 2):

I am the one who approve this edit,

But in past I have rejected many edits done by you , because your edit may conflict with authors intent.

You are editing post basis on authors comments I personally think its not good,because its depend on authors to add that comment in their post or not.

and for edit review I always read editors comments, so I get better idea why He/she edited that post.

So I think its good for all reviewer to read that comment

Comment: Hi Murtuza. Yes. I understood now what you all are telling. Thanks for consider murtuza. and for replying to my questions on stack exchange. thank you

Comment: You are always welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the reason they put for reject.

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read,
>   easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either
>   completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

Now how to behave after rejection on review

**You must respect other fellow community member opinion.**

In my opinion  It should be **Approve**

> *Now remove the fellow community member name and their profile link too*

Comment: ok sir, i agree with you. but what i am thinking is, i just changed no no i just corrected the spellings. i think, that also useful for site.

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara it is useful but it depend on reviewer how he sees the edit.

Comment: Yes. i agree. I have removed sir, i always respect you type of people who are responsible for others questions sir. thank you